# selnolig Turns en and em Dashes into Hyphens if polyglossia is loaded Before the Fonts

Tags: fonts, fontspec, polyglossia, ligatures, selnolig

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Stix Two Text}
\usepackage{selnolig}

\begin{document}
-- ---
\end{document}
```

Of which the output is `-- ---`, instead of an en-dash and an em-dash.

However, if I load the font before polyglossia, the output is as expected: `– —`.

I don't understand much about the inner working of TeX and friends, could someone tell me what is going on here? Is it usually best practice to load polyglossia after the fonts? Or is this solely a problem with selnolig?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

polyglossia forces the default renderer to harfbuzz, and selnolig doesn't work with this renderer. Loading the font before polyglossia is fine, or you can force node renderer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Stix Two Text}[Renderer=Node]

\usepackage{selnolig}

\begin{document}
-- ---
\end{document}
```